# Xcode reload complete UITableViewController

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have a `tableviewcontroller` with some sections which can be collapsed and expanded. 
it is also possible to add new sections to my tableview.

But newly added sections are only visible after closing and reopening the tableview.

Somehow, I need to reload the whole tableview after adding a section.
[tableview reloadData] doesnt work.

So how can I manually reload the complete tableview without closing and reopening 
the window? (or at least the user shouldn't notice a close and re-open operation).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :

```
- (IBAction)refreshButton: (id)sender {
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

or it might be this

```
- (IBAction)refreshButton: (id)sender {
     [self reloadTableData];
}
```

Hope it works!